# SwiftyJSON extremely slow JSON iteration

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am using a lib SwiftyJSON.swift. I successfully import a valid JSON file but it's very large (500kb) (actually a gpx-file from Strava).

The code below is VERY slow, about one integration per second! Why? And what can I do about it?

```
for index in 0...json1["trk"]["trkseg"]["trkpt"].length-1 {

    lat = Double(json1["trk"]["trkseg"]["trkpt"][index]["@attributes"]["lat"].asString!)!

    long = Double(json1["trk"]["trkseg"]["trkpt"][index]["@attributes"]["lon"].asString!)!
}
```

Comment: 1. Use SwiftyJSON
2. 0...json1 is obsolete, for x in y is enough

Comment: Try to put the `json1["trk"]["trkseg"]["trkpt"]` into a constant and access the constant in the loop.

Comment: Please read the document carefully before use https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following change could speed up your code a bit:

```
let array = json1["trk"]["trkseg"]["trkpt"]
for bla in array {
    lat = Double(bla["@attributes"]["lat"].asString!)!
    long = Double(bla["@attributes"]["lon"].asString!)!
}
```